# Disable schemachange change history table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, schemachange

Is it possible to disable *Change History Table* in [schemachange](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange)?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to disable it. It's the metadata repository of all changes:

https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange/tree/master#change-history-table

> schemachange records all applied changes scripts to the change history
> table. By default schemachange will attempt to log all activities to
> the METADATA.SCHEMACHANGE.CHANGE_HISTORY table.